# jQuery not working with WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I think there is a conflict with the way WordPress uses jQuery:

Tried:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hello');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Tried also:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

And Firebug dumps:

```
jQuery is not defined
[Detener en este error] }(jQuery));
```

And also tried:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   alert("hello");
});
```

and Firebug:

```
jQuery is not defined
[Detener en este error] jQuery.noConflict();
```

And jQuery **is** imported

Any idea what am i missing?

Comment: Do you have jQuery included *before* your script? Also, a link to your site could help people answer your question.

Comment: how are you including jquery?

Comment: You *sure* it's imported? You tried to view source and it's there, and the URL is correct? And `$` and `jQuery` aren't defined in the firebug console?

Comment: I can't find your jquery include anywhere on that site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like jQuery is not available (neither the `$` variable nor `jQuery` were defined). In your particular case, it's because the library is not loaded at all. Put the next code in your `<head>` section **before** your the scripts requiring jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so how is it posible that the search input with is animated onClick??

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet The animation ("slide") in done with CSS. The removal of the text "Search" is done with HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

How are you including jquery? Whatever the case may be, its not happening (check out the head / check out the page DOM via firebug - no $ or jQuery references).

The correct way to link the hosted version of jquery (and in this case, a dependent plugin) in wordpress looks like this:

in **functions.php** (or a plugin... or whatever)

```
// register scripts 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_register){
function thickbox_register() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
    wp_register_script( 'thickbox', 'path to thickbox'.thickbox.js, 'jquery');
    }  
}   
add_action('init', 'thickbox_register');

//print the now registered scripts 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_enqueue){
function thickbox_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
    }  
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'thickbox_enqueue');

// do the same for css 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_style_enqueue){
function thickbox_style_enqueue() {
    wp_register_style( 'thickbox', 'path to css'.thickbox.css );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );
    }  
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'thickbox_style_enqueue');
```

To ensure wordpress delivers the correct scripts at the correct time, you must add actions to the init and register script wordpress methods.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

even if your document works now, for better practive :

1. change all your $ sign with "Jquery" . (conflicting with wordpress core)
2. you are not declaring class or id .

for example in your code :

```
  $('header').hide();
```

should be

```
jQuery('#branding').hide();
```

and

```
$('body').css('position','relative');
```

should be

```
jQuery('.home').css('position','relative');
```

your code is semantic , where header is not a  tag, but a  tag , meaning header is not a class or id (rather #branding is an id ) and body as well (rather .home or .blog)
better practice would be to declare the class .

Answer (score 0):

Checked the URL you have posted and there seems to be no reference to jQuery.

Include the below code inside head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code in `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```